# R: indexing result from a regular expression

Tags: regex, r, indexing, string-matching

I am trying to use the indexes that were returned from searching through a string for every instance of a character.  When I use gregexp (pattern, text),

```
lookfor<-"n"
string<-"ATTnGGCnATTn"
gregexpr(pattern=lookfor,text=string)
```

I get the following:

```
[[1]]

[1]  4  8  12

attr(,"match.length")

[1] 1 1 1

attr(,"useBytes")

[1] TRUE
```

How do I index through the first line to be able to use those locations?  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Except that's an invalid regular expression.

Comment: @Richard You are right.

Comment: Are you searching for the letter `n`?

Comment: @Richard I am looking for the position of each letter n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Addition (2) :** After thinking about this for a while, I came to the conclusion that you could have simply used `unlist` on your original `gregexpr` call

```
> unlist(gregexpr("n", string))
# [1]  4  8 12
```

---

From your comment

> I am looking for the position of each letter n

it follows that you could do any of these:

```
> which(strsplit(string, "")[[1]] == "n")
# [1]  4  8 12
> cumsum(nchar(strsplit(string, "n")[[1]])+1)
# [1]  4  8 12
> nc <- 1:nchar(string)
> which(substring(string, nc, nc) == "n")
# [1]  4  8 12
```

**Addition (1) in regards to the similar strings (comment in another answer) :** You could use `strsplit` again, and locate those values with one of the methods above

```
> string2 <- "ATTTGGCCATTG"
> w <- which(strsplit(string, "")[[1]] == "n")
> strsplit(string2, "")[[1]][w]
[1] "T" "C" "G"
```

Comment: exactly!  The first three out of the four generous options are precisely what I needed.  The final was the problem I kept running into in that I can't access the locations.

Comment: Hah! That is the next step, naturally.  I needed just the numerical position to be able to locate those changes for a large number of strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract all the matches, you can use the builtin function `regmatches()`

```
m <- gregexpr(regexp,string)
regmatches(string,m)
```

This will return a list of character vectors because string can be greater than length 1. If you're only passing one string in, you can get at the vector of matches bypassing the list with

```
regmatches(string,m)[[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I try your suggestion I get the search term in the gregexpr, in this case the "n", but not the locations in the string.

Comment: @SeaJane Well, first of all your example doesn't appear to be a valid regular expression so it's a bit hard to test. The `{n}` is invalid syntax and R throws an error for me. Is that exactly what you ran?

Comment: I tried to get something to work sooo many times that I posted something ridiculous, in lieu of simplification, forgive me.  I used regexp<-"n", m<-gregexpr(regexp, string).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step method to find the indices.  I suspect there are more efficient ways to achieve the same result.  The argument fixed = TRUE tells R to look for the literal lower case "n" rather than treat it as a regular expression.

Having done so, the [[1]] portion at the end retains only the indices element of the list

To show all indices, use the `length` function.

```
string="ATTnGGCnATTn"
index  <- gregexpr(pattern = "n", text = string, fixed = TRUE)[[1]] 
first.index  <- index[1:length(index)]
```

Comment: I tried your example, but the result looks like this: <br/> **[[1]] <br/> [1]  4 8 12 <br/> attr(,"match.length") <br/> [1] 1 1 1 <br/>
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE** <br/> The result is formatted such that the length is 1.

Comment: 2583119, sorry about the formatting above. I tried your example, but the result looks like this:    **[[1]]    [1] 4 8 12    attr(,"match.length")    [1] 1 1 1    attr(,"useBytes") [1] TRUE**   The result is formatted such that the length is 1.

Comment: SeaJane, I just now copied the three lines (starting with string = and ending with index)] and got this result when I ran it.  [1]  4  8 12

Comment: @2582119 Yes, thanks.  The locations are correct, the problem is the access to those locations.  I cannot coerce the data into something where I can take location 4 8 or 12 and then use those locations to find information in similar strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my own answer!
Using the Biostrings package in Bioconductor:

```
string<-"ATTnGGCnATTn"  
matches<-matchPattern(pattern="n", subject=string)
m<-as.vector(ranges(matches))
```

Now I can call up each position of of "n" in all similar strings. Thank you for those that took the time to answer.

Comment: You should really look into package `stringr`

Comment: @Richard which function do you suggest in stringr?

Comment: Well I still don't know exactly what you're doing, but `str_locate_all(string, "n")` gives the same result as `gregexpr(pattern=lookfor,text=string)[[1]]`, as well as `> which(strsplit(string, "")[[1]] == "n")` which gives `4  8 12`

Comment: @Richard sorry I haven't been able to explain myself well.  The results of all of these are the same, true.  What I would like to do is to use the results.  I need to access each location and find data from similar strings in that exact position.

Comment: Okay, not a problem.  What is one of the similar strings?

Comment: @ Richard One of the similar strings would be "ATTTGGCCATTG".  I am looking to find the differences in the "n" position.